# Remove double-click style from control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a PictureBox control which internally generates the following Windows messages when I click rapidly:

```
* WM_LBUTTONDOWN
* WM_LBUTTONUP
* WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK
* WM_LBUTTONUP
```

Is there any way to remove the double-click style from the control, perhaps in the form's constructor? In Delphi I am able to do this using this code:

```
// Prevent TImage from generating OnDblClick event notifications 
btnShift.ControlStyle := (btnShift.ControlStyle - [csDoubleClicks]);
```

Without handling both the Click and DoubleClick events, how would I achieve the same thing in C#?

Comment: If you don't handle the event, does it matter that windows is generating it?

Comment: @Levesque: Unfortunately, yes. If the control produces both Click and DoubleClick events, you'll handle roughly half the number of events overall if you handle only one or the other ie. rapidly clicking the control will seem sluggish compared to another control that only produces Click events. AFAIK, the most elegant way to resolve this is to prevent the control generating DoubleClick events ie. only Click events are generated. How is this done in C#, though?

Comment: Hmm, one technique that works is to route both the Click and DoubleClick events through a single handler. This feels inelegant though. Would be best to prevent the DoubleClick event in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

Override the default class styles in a new control

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NoDblClickPic
{
    public partial class NoDblClickPicControl : PictureBox
    {
        private const int CS_DBLCLKS = 0x8;

        public NoDblClickPicControl()
        {
        }

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ClassStyle &= ~CS_DBLCLKS;
                return cp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, that works...unfortunately I'm looking to implement this in two applications, one on the full and another on the Compact Framework versions of .NET (one version runs on Win7 and the other, a cut-down version, on WinCE). "CreateParams" is not supported in the CF, so just looking into how I might do this using PInvoke or similar. Thanks!